# How can I open native camera from my app on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, deep-linking

I need open the native camera app when a function was called. I just need redirect to native camera app. I don't want to get any image.

I am trying with this code:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some-camera-deep-link://"];
        
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"some error");
        }
```

However, I don't know the exact URL I need to set and how configure this in my `Info.plist`.

Is possible do this kind of navigation?
Can you show some example?

I don't want to use `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: As you can see from [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+open+camera+app), it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. There are a few URL schemes that are supported by the system. And the camera is none of them. You have to use a built-in component such as `UIImagePickerController` or create a new one on your own.

AFAIK, at most, you can able to open the gallery with this `photos-redirect://`.

This [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference) indicates all these supported links.

**Updated**: I've found this helpful [repo](https://github.com/bhagyas/app-urls) if you're curious.